# How to query a query result?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I created query to fetch top selling products. Now, **I want to query this result**, for example, **top 100 products order by SerialNo** or **top 100 products order by SellingQty**... etc..

Here is my query which give all products order by totalOrders :

```
    SELECT tblProducts.skuCode,tblProducts.productCode, tblProducts.productName, COUNT(tblOrders_Products.delivered) as totalOrder
    FROM tblOrders_Products INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblOrders_Products.productID = tblProducts.productID
    WHERE tblProducts.productName is not null
    GROUP BY tblOrders_Products.delivered, tblOrders_Products.productID, tblProducts.skuCode,     tblProducts.productName,tblProducts.productCode
    ORDER BY totalOrder
```

I considered to create a view. But many posts are telling that, using Order By clause with view, [is harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx) or not give result sometime, So, I am wondering how this can be done?

I can do this in .NET by sorting `DataTable`, and using that as DataSource. But how it can be done in SQL SERVER?

And which way is faster? Ordering in SQL Server or in `DataTable`?
I am using SQL SERVER 2005.

Thanks.

Comment: add `TOP` clause in your select staement, eg, `SELECT TOP 100 SELECT  tblProducts.skuCode,tblProducts.productCode, tblProducts.productName, .....`

Comment: Grouping by a total order will allow you to inspect the TOP(X) or TOP(X) percent FROM your Query

Comment: Do you want to Order By SerialNo or Order By SellingQty AFTER your Order By totalOrder? Or do you just want to be able to switch the Order By parameter?

Comment: Always try to do these sort of data crunching at your database rather than in the business logic. SQL server will use the best strategy to connect the tables and will use the best indexes around to fetch and filter the data you want. If you get a lot of rows returned from the initial query, and if you decide to the filtering in the application layer, all those records will have to cross process boundaries and potentially network boundaries to reach the DataSet in the business layer. If view is not the thing for you, try considering a stored procedure with some procedural logic to filter data

Comment: I feel you all taking wrong perception of my question. I want to query the resultset filled by this query. I can't modify my query as it is giving me all top selling products. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the Top 100 products ordered by SerialNo (I assumed it was a part of tblProducts here).

You can switch the Order By parameter to get it ordered the other fields.

```
SELECT a.skuCode, a.productCode, a.productName, a.totalOrder, a.SerialNo
FROM
(
SELECT TOP 100 tblProducts.skuCode,tblProducts.productCode, tblProducts.productName, COUNT(tblOrders_Products.delivered) as totalOrder, tblProducts.SerialNo
    FROM tblOrders_Products INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblOrders_Products.productID = tblProducts.productID
    WHERE tblProducts.productName is not null
    GROUP BY tblOrders_Products.delivered, tblOrders_Products.productID, tblProducts.skuCode,     tblProducts.productName,tblProducts.productCode
    ORDER BY totalOrder) a
ORDER BY a.SerialNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
WITH TopProducts AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 tblProducts.productID, COUNT(tblOrders_Products.delivered) as totalOrder
    FROM tblOrders_Products INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblOrders_Products.productID = tblProducts.productID
    WHERE tblProducts.productName is not null
    GROUP BY tblProducts.productID 
    ORDER BY COUNT(tblOrders_Products.delivered) DESC
)
SELECT * 
FROM TopProducts INNER JOIN tblProducts ON TopProducts.productID = tblProducts.productID
ORDER BY tblProducts.SerialNo
```

The TopProducts is called a Common Table Expression in SQL Server, and it's a neat way to reuse query parts.

Sorting a DataTable in .NET will woks as well. You will probably not notice any difference in performance for only 100 rows. Sorting on the client would actually be preferrable in a scenario when the user may want to sort the results in different ways, e.g. by clicking column headers in a grid, since this can be accomplished without a separate database call.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, and introducing me to new concept. I tried but getting Parse Error for query near to 'AS'. I checked some references and tried to put column names next to AS, but still getting same error.